# How to terminate unresponsive phpdbg console?

Tags: phpdbg

I wonder how to terminate phpdbg process from within its interactive console.

There were several situations when i need it.

First, when i try to print object content with infinite recursion.

Second, when it hangs after for example usage of bad `readline_completion_function` defined in `.phpdbginit`.

`CTRL+c` combination have no affect.

Comment: yes, ctrl+c is intercepted by phpdbg. will look at the readline_completion_function...

Comment: hmm, what's the issue with that function? works for me here.

Comment: For killing I recommend `ctrl+z` and then `kill -9 %1`. I don't see any good way. You also have that behavior with other debuggers though. What'd be a great idea is simple paging (like gdb has). À la `--- Press <return> to continue, <q> to quit ---`.

Comment: @bwoebi, just tried as you recommend `ctrl+z`, but i doesn't work for me. Only thing it does is print: `^Z`. How should it work?

Comment: @bwoebi, about `readline_completion_function` i'll later make some test sample to reproduce this error i have told

Comment: @bwoebi, about pager, it would be great if we can use different system pagers from unix shell, such as `less`. I'd really love to have an opportunity to use `less` because of it's feature of search in content it handles, and some more features cool features to go next and prev using different shortcuts.

Comment: no idea, but ctrl+z usually should trigger a SIGSTP… are you using Windows? Well… then no idea.

Comment: The issue with using a pager is that you can't scroll back a bit later (e.g. to compare two outputs). I don't really see how I can integrate this nicely, sorry.

Comment: @bwoebi But if you output really big object or array you will have the same problem, you won't be able to scroll back because all screens will be filled with your current output and more you even can't be able to get to the beginning of your current output. Pager can be additional tool to output some data, but not the only one. In general output will go like it goes now, and in addition we can output something using pager. I think for those who want to use pager instead of general output, the scroll back issue is not a problem.